# How to make the image go on top of the box like in this image using html and css

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
.box {
  margin: 0px 190px 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  padding: .25rem .75rem .75rem;
  background-color: #2a3047;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.img-cont {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="box">
    This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><img src="../pics/pexels-august-de-richelieu-4260325.jpg" class="img-cont"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried this html and css code for the image over box but the results where nothing like what i had in mind

Comment: what do you need here, Box over image or image over box? As in shared image it has box over image

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you really want, what you say isn't the same of what you show. But I guess you mean this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  top: 10%;
  margin: 0px 190px 0px 25px;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  padding: .25rem .75rem .75rem;
  background-color: #2a3047;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.img-cont {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <span><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3dn7.jpg?s=256&g=1" class="img-cont"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!This is a box!
  </div>

</section>
```

In other words you should position the image as `relative` and the box as `absolute`